# Is it possible to block an Erlang process on delivering a messsage?

Tags: concurrency, erlang, message-queue

There is a very common trick for emulating synchronous communication in Erlang:

```erlang
%% Process 'sender'
Ref = make_ref(),
'receiver' ! {self(), Ref, Message},
receive {ack, Ref} -> ok end,
...


%% Process 'receiver'
receive
    {From, Ref, Message} ->
         From ! {ack, Ref},
         handle_msg(Message),
         ...
end
```

This lets `sender` block until the message is received by the `receiver`. What I am looking for however, is to block until the message is *delivered*, or in other words until lands in the message queue of the receiving process. The importance is in that I want to combine it with assumptions about the order of messages that already have been queued, without having to wait for the message being picked from the queue (it may not even be picked ever, I don't care).

For instance, given:

```erlang
%% Process 'sender'
send_deliver('receiver', first),
'proxy' ! second


%% Process 'receiver'
receive
  unlock -> ok
end,
receive
  X -> X
end


%% Process 'proxy'
receive
  X -> 'receiver' ! X
end


%% Process 'unlocker'
timer:sleep(thousand_years()),
'receiver' ! unlock
```

My goals in this example are:

- `receiver` **must** receive `first` before `second` *EDIT:* unless it listens on a pattern which doesn't match `first` but matches `second`
- The message payload should be irrelevant (e.g. if you flipped `first` and `second`, then `second` would have to be received first)
- How long `sender` is blocked on the call to `send_deliver/2` should not depend on what `receiver` is doing (in particular, it should not be forced to wait for a `thousand_years`)
- I am fine wrapping messages with tuples and adding additional information, just like in the synchronous-send trick

Plus, universally I want to preserve all message filtering capabilities as well all assumptions about message ordering. Is there some built-in trick for that in Erlang or a pattern which would allow me to emulate those semantics?

Answer (score 2):

The ERTS only guarantees the message ordering between two processes, no other semantics are guaranteed. In the case of distributed messaging, messages can even be lost.

Under the hood, it uses locks to deliver messages between local processes, but once you cross node boundaries you're on your own. I'd avoid relying on internal implementation that's not guaranteed to remain the same.

Regarding your problem, what I've done when I faced this issue is just consider the `second` message as `first+second` and prepare the receiver for `first` messages received out of order:

```erlang
receiver() ->
  receive
    first ->
      do_first(),
      receive second -> do_second() end,
    second -> do_first(), do_second(), receive first -> ok end end
  end.
```

In this solution is up to you how to handle out of order `first` messages. You can use `reference()` to match pairs of `first` and `second`, aliases to deactivate the receiver, etc...

Other option is to make the message flow lineal:
`Sender -> Proxy -> Receiver` where the `first` and `second` messages are sent by the Proxy

Comment: Your example locks up the receiver to receiving both messages right after another with nothing in the meantime, which is not something I want. My problem focuses on locking on delivering a message, that first/second thing was just an example consequence. Maybe I didn't articulate it enough, tho. But nevertheless, I take the answer that it's not something I can get in ERTS.

Comment: You can model the fsm however you want, receiving events and mutating the internal state at your will, the key is to account for message passing out of order instead of relying on unguaranteed behaviour from the VM. You can match pairs of messages and act only when both have been received. Even if you somehow block the sender until the message is in the receiver's queue, you don't know when it's going to be `receive`d by the receiver.